# Error adding or deleting plugins in cordova / phone gap

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have cordova 3.3 installed (in 3.2, have the same error) and when i want to add or remove a plugin the system show this error:

```
>>cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.network-information
Fetching plugin from "org.apache.cordova.network-information"...
Starting installation of "org.apache.cordova.network-information" for android

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

I check the path and is correct:

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/Users/manuelcm/Documents/sdk_android/platform-tools:
/Users/manuelcm/Documents/sdk_android/tools:/usr/local/apache-ant/bin:
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

In my first installation i install the plugins and the plugins directories appear in /plugins/ but after build in iOS only de device plugin appear in /platforms/ios/www/plugins this is the reason that I want to reinstall the plugins.

Anyone know why this is happening and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem, first I created the project in local disk. 
The problem persisted, then I created the project with uppercase in the first letter of project name, and all works fine. Yes, it seems incredible, but this was the solution.

Comment: I know some time passed, but before you start using cordova commands, you have to initiate any project, because it is downloading and creating local files to use later.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after I upgraded to cordova 3.3.0, when I tried 'cordova rm' the plugins (after I removed android.json from the plugins folder).
But the problem resolved for me when after I ran 'cordova add' all the plugins.

- So I suppose you could try 'cordova plugin list' to see if it knows which plugin is added.
  if it does know then try removing 'plugins/android.json' then add each of the plugin back in follow by 'cordova build'.
- Also if you have angularjs, you might want to remove the /docs for it as it could also produce the error
- And you might want to check your /platform/android/project.properties is it using a target that you are expecting? (e.g. android-16 but you don't have it set up?)

Comment: Hi, I have this problem also in 3.2. Now I delete all the plugins directory and the plugins in /android/src/org/apache/cordova, but the problem persist. I can add the plugins (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;) the plugin has created in plugins directory and  /android/src/org/apache/cordova but after the error the add script stop and not add the plugin to ios. I'm a little desesperate.

Comment: Did you try deleting the /platforms/android/../../plugins/android.json and add them back in? Then 'cordova build'?

Comment: Yes, I tried it. I also tried to create the project again, but when I add the plugin the system ever throw the "SyntaxError: Unexpected token error" when install the android plugin.

Comment: Do you get error running this manually?   `ant debug -f "/platforms/android/build.xml"`?  It might tell you where it's failing... Anyway I encountered the problem again after upgrading my angularjs library and fixed it by removing the angular/docs.. so if you use angularjs with your cordova.``

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, actually i'm in christmas holidays until January 7. When come back I chek this and say something.

Comment: Hi,  when execute `ant debug -f ".....build.xml"` i get the error `BUILD FAILED
/Users/manuelcm/Documents/sdk_android/tools/ant/build.xml:653: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/manuelcm/Documents/sdk_android/tools/ant/build.xml:698: null returned: 1` I have searched a solution (I add java_home and android_home to .profile), but the problem persists. Also, i have created the project again and i get this error when execute `cordova build android` with the demo project.

Comment: Hi, I check the target of android and is correct, also remove and add the plugins and recreate the project.

Comment: Sounds like something might be wrong with your android SDK (unlikely though....?)? If you look at your /Users/manuelcm/Documents/sdk_android/tools/ant/build.xml where gen.absolute.dir is defined, do it look right? (mine looks like did it generate the said directory? in my case /platform/android/gen)?

Comment: Ok One last try..... in /platform/android/project.properties file do you have something like 'android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib' where CordovaLib is where the cordova library src and bin and gen folder resides. If not then add it in and try again...

Comment: Hi florence,
In build.xml the gen.absolute.dir is defined with the default value (location="gen"). I try /platform/android/gen but it doesn't work, because detect that the directory is incorrect. So that's not the problem. 
I also check project.properties and verify the android library reference is set to "android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib". In the same directory of project.properties exists the CordovaLib directory with the src, bin and gen folder.The strangest thing is that I downloaded the sdk and created the project again (using the test project "device is ready") but the build fail.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue while installing org.apache.cordova.dialogs plugin. I deleted content under www folder and executed the same command. It worked. Under www folder I had my project which uses Angular. Not sure if angular has any conflict with this.

Comment: Angularjs codes in www directory should have no impacts on the cordova project.