# Error deleting cordova plugin

Tags: android, ios, cordova, plugins, plugman

I am trying just to delete a plugin from my cordova project. It should be simple but I don't know why its having an error.

> cordova plugin list

shows me this:

cordova-plugin-customurlscheme 4.0.0 "Custom URL scheme"

cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.1.1 "Notification"

cordova-plugin-file 3.0.1-dev "File"

cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.2.2-dev "File Transfer"

and when I run

> cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-customurlscheme

it shows me :

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token /
at Object.parse (native)
at Function.PlatformJson.load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/util/PlatformJson.js:35:21)
at runUninstallPlatform (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/uninstall.js:233:37)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/uninstall.js:94:16
at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44
at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

What this could be ?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20631138/error-adding-or-deleting-plugins-in-cordova-phone-gap

Comment: I have had strange issues with plugins before. You could try to remove all the plugins by deleting the  plugin directory. Then just add them back in.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when the plugin itself was not coded properly. Try delete the following:

```
\plugins\cordova-plugin-customurlscheme (or whatever the folder name)
```

reference to it in `\plugins\fetch.json` and `\plugins\android.json` (or ios)

```
\www\plugins\cordova-plugin-customurlscheme
```

(the reference in this file) `\www\plugins\cordova_plugins.js`

If that doesn't work. Just recreate the whole app and add the other plugins back in, and then add the source code back in.